How to increase the maximum number of read registers to 256 in libmodbus?
I want to increase the number of readable registers in libmodbus to 256. I changed the variables:
#define MODBUS_MAX_READ_REGISTERS 256

#define MODBUS_RTU_MAX_ADU_LENGTH 512

#define MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH 1000

Then I query the registers
int result2 = modbus_read_input_registers(ctx, 0x1000, 128, tab_reg);

but I'm getting an error
ERROR CRC received 0xFD08 != CRC calculated 0xFAB2

what could I do to increase the maximum number of registers to read?

The response packet to a "read input registers" command uses a single byte to indicate the length of the returned data.  Since the registers are two bytes each, a length of 128 or more would cause the length byte to wrap around to zero, making the entire packet invalid.  MODBUS_MAX_READ_REGISTERS and the other limits have their specific values for a reason!

Can you perform two separate reads?
It's actually not allowed to have a message of more than 256 bytes in Modbus RTU... As you can find here and on Wikipedia (citing the source: the Modbus protocol description) as well.
So neither the library, nor the specific Modbus slave device you send your request to, is required to support your attempt to send a bigger data frame.
As jasonharper pointed out in a comment: a response message only has a single byte to indicate the response message length (in number of bytes). A larger response length would cause the message to be invalid (the code would check the length byte, compare to the amount of bytes in the message and evaluate the message to invalid). I have seen in other implementations than libmodbus that instead of "length invalid", I got a "CRC error". Unfortunately the wrong error, but still correct behaviour that you get an error, of course.
